# No video in Microsoft teams in Win 7 VM

Tags: windows-7, virtualbox

Due to company policy we are forced to work with Microsoft Team for our communications. Unfortunately, being a Linux user, there really isn't any working native client for me, official or 3rd party, ( Even tried Sky Linux ).

Wine also did not work, and being as new as it is there seem to be no existing attempts documented for it yet.

So I tried a Windows 7 virtual machine that I had running for testing purposes. ( For the record, yes I also tried Windows 8 and 10, both of which have audio issues with my headset )

It all works fine, including calling, but there is no video. I can't see webcams and I can't see screenshares. Both of which are quite essential for me. 
I can share my screen without any issue, but if someone else shares his screen I just get nothing.

Now I've tried quite a bit to get it working. Changed the network to bridged, changed the network drivers to the KVM ones for better performance. 
I tried figuring out which ports Teams uses, but haven't found it yet. So I tried to explicitly give access to the ports I know for skype and skype for business. Still no effect.

I installed the experimental Direct3D drivers, in case it was a video performance issue. I gave the VM the maximum amount of video memory Virtualbox allows.

Nothing so far. Not even an error or message when someone connects. 
I've considered that it might have to do with the video being shown on a different layer which Vbox doesn't virtualize ( I've had this issue with a Windows XP vm many years ago ) but I can't find anything hinting to that.

So, I'm stumped. I hope someone here can help me!

Comment: I will also accept any answer that will allow me to use Teams on Linux in a more native way, whether it's a 3rd party client, or something like Wine, or anything else. 
But dualboot is not an option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end the solution proved to be performance related. Once I increased the CPU a bit, the memory AND the GPU memory, it all worked.

There seems to be some switch in the application that doesn't allow video call unless there are enough resources available. Which makes sense, I suppose :)

Comment: Any idea what the magic thresholds for resources are? Teams isn't showing or capturing video on my Windows 7 VM (in virtualbox) and I thought I allocated a lot of resources.

Comment: Try installing the Direct3d drivers. It will make your screen flicker most likely, but video should work.

Comment: Oohw, and the video memory is the most important resource. I have 256mb there